# Andorid VideoView not adding VTT subtitles in player

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using
videoView.addSubtitleSource(new FileInputStream(subtitle.getPath()), MediaFormat.createSubtitleFormat("text/vtt", subtitle.getLanguage()));
to add subtitle file in the view.

The file is valid and in MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener when I look for getTrackInfo, I get the subtitle track info however the subtitles are not showing up.

Any idea as to how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265859/android-kitkat-videoview-addsubtitlesource check this link answer, may be it should helpful to you.

Comment: https://github.com/sakurabird/Android-Example-HLS-ExoPlayer.

You can use exoplayer

Answer (score 0):

After trying this find an answer to this for days, my colleague shared with me [this video by DevBytes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCRGc2PcmB8) I noticed from it that I wasn't doing this:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_closed_caption, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.closedCaptionMenuItem -> {
            startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_CAPTIONING_SETTINGS))
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Essentially I hadn't enabled captioning in the settings and thus weren't showing up. Hopefully, this helps you. Good day